# Como retirar o "\n" com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma variável que recebe o seguinte conteúdo:

```
dadosP.formapgto = $('input[name=opcaoPagamento]:checked')
  .parent().text();
```

Porém eu recebo alguns `\n` dentro dessa string, como segue a foto exemplar

[image: Imagem com /n]

O que também interfere no resultado final:

[image: resultado final]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não precisa utilizar jQuery para isso. Utilize o método [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), do próprio JavaScript.

Por exemplo:

```js
const str = '       \n            \n pix\n';

// Remove os espaços em branco.
const result = str.trim();

console.log({ str, result });
```

O jQuery possui a função [`$.trim`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/), que remove espaços em branco do início e fim de uma string, assim como o método `trim` do JS. No entanto, como vimos acima, uma vez que o JavaScript possui nativamente método com essa funcionalidade, essa função foi depreciada e não é mais encorajada pelos próprios autores do jQuery.

Em suma, bastaria fazer:

```
$('input[name=opcaoPagamento]:checked')
  .parent().text().trim();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu super certo, obrigado mesmo amigo! :)